# Fazer consulta não mostrando alguns resultados

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, query

Tenho uma Tabela de **CPF** onde fica os **CPF's** cadastrados. 
Preciso fazer um `SELECT` onde exiba todos os CPF's cadastrados, **menos** 3 CPF's.

Algo tipo:

```
 SELECT * 
   FROM cpf 
  WHERE cpf_id <> '111.111.111.11,222.222.222.22,333.333.333.33';
```

Qual a forma correta de fazer esse tipo de consulta?

Answer (score 5):

Use o `NOT IN ()`.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM cpf 
 WHERE cpf_id NOT IN ( '111.111.111.11'
                      ,'222.222.222.22'
                      ,'333.333.333.33');
```

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado.